# Scroll to element on page, and then run callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery's `.animate` to scroll to an element on a page, and then execute a callback.

After searching around, I found this function:

```
function scrollToElement(selector, callback){
    var animation = {scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top};
    $('html,body').animate(animation, 'slow', 'swing', callback);
}
```

This correctly scrolls to the element defined by 'selector', but callback is called twice (because `$('html,body')` contains 2 elements).

I tried changing

```
$('html,body').animate
```

to:

```
$(document).animate
```

and:

```
$(window).animate
```

but, neither of those do anything.

I also tried changing the function to this:

```
$('html').animate(animation, 'slow', 'swing', function(){
    $('body').animate(animation, 'slow', 'swing', callback);
});
```

but, this made the browser run the 1st animation and then the 2nd, so I had wait for both to run before the callback was ran (I dont't want that).

I figured out that `$('body').scrollTop()` only works in Chrome, and `$('html').scrollTop()` only works in Firefox.

So, is there a way (without needing to download a jQuery plugin) for me to scroll to a specific element in both Chrome and Firefox (I don't care about IE), and have a callback executed (once)?

**EDIT**:

I made a crude fix by making a boolean to check if the callback ran already, and if it was, don't run it again.

```
function scrollToElement(selector, callback){
    var animation = {scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top};
    var callback_running = false;
    $('html,body').animate(animation, 'slow', 'swing', function(){
        if(typeof callback == 'function' && !callback_running){
            callback_running = true;
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I made a crude fix, that checks if the function was already ran.  Is there another way to fix this though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work too

```
function scrollToElement(selector, callback){
    var animation = {scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top};
    $('html,body').animate(animation, 'slow', 'swing', function() {
        if (typeof callback == 'function') {
            callback();
        }
        callback = null;
    });
}
```

Comment: but this doesn't call the callback again when animation is run, suppose we clicked back to top once more

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery 1.5 (or can upgrade to it), you can use the new [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) syntax.

```
$.fn.scrollToElement = function(selector, callback) {
    var def = new $.Deferred(),
        el = this;

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top}, 'slow', 'swing', def.resolve);

    if (callback) {
        def.promise().done(function(){
            callback.call(el);
        });
    }
};

$('html, body').scrollToElement('#foo', function() {
    alert('done scrolling');
});
```

Because a deferred object can only be resolved once, you can't have more than one call to the callback.

Comment: The new deferred stuff in jQuery looks neat, but I don't know to use it.  Also, will upgrading to jQuery 1.5 break anything (I am using jQuery 1.4.2)?

Comment: @Rocket Shouldn't be a problem, unless there are any plugins that do unusual things.

Comment: Deferred does basically the same thing here as the boolean check, but in a more roundabout way. It won't fix any underlying issues.

Comment: This code is for work, so I'd need to ask my boss if we could upgrade, and I'm not sure what plugins we have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
$(document.body).animate( ... )
```

Comment: That's the same as `$('body').animate` which doesn't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

how about using a DIV that stretches over the full document body and do the animation on that DIV instead? you can't be sure how many more browser issues you can find otherwise (i.e. how many more browsers would not animate HTML nor BODY for instance)

Comment: `$('#wrapper').animate({scrollTop: 100})` doesn't do anything.

Comment: ok, in that case - have you tried this plugin yet? http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid animating both html and body elements. Your page animation will work correctly on every modern or old browser and the callback will run once (as it should) by the addition of a simple condition in your function.

```
function scrollToElement(selector, callback){
    var scrollElem='html';
    //animate body for webkit browsers that don't support html animation
    if($.browser.webkit){ 
        scrollElem='body';
    }
    var animation = {scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top};
    $(scrollElem).animate(animation, 'slow', 'swing', callback);
}
```

Only webkit doesn't support "html" animation, so you change the "scrollElem" variable accordingly. In addition, scrolling a single element (html or body) works much better on older browsers (e.g. previous versions of Opera).

Comment: jQuery is supposed to be cross-browser, once I start needing to use [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/), something's not right.  Also, the docs say `[We] recommend against using this property`.

Comment: Well, when you start using $.support it's the same thing... something is not right. In fact a lot of things are not right, especially with the number of desktop and mobile browsers out there. 

There are times when $.browser is faster, lighter and easier than $.support and in my opinion, in this case is better. jQuery suggest using $.support over $.browser for future code maintainability but this doesn't apply in this case.