# How can I scroll to the div automatically when I click the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have a button at the top, 4 tables in the middle and a div (id="MasterDiv") on the bottom of a page. How can I scroll to the div automatically when I click the button?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659354/jquery-scroll-down-page-a-set-increment-in-pixels-on-click

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this function (which uses jQuery's `.animate`)

```
function scrollToElement(selector, callback){
    var animation = {scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top};
    $('html,body').animate(animation, 'slow', 'swing', function() {
        if (typeof callback == 'function') {
            callback();
        }
        callback = null;
    });
}
```

You call it like this:

```
scrollToElement('#MasterDiv');
```

Or if you want to include a callback:

```
scrollToElement('#MasterDiv', function(){
  alert('Page scrolled');
});
```

Comment: That function is from a question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019951

Comment: You should consider accepting that answer from your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019951/scroll-to-element-on-page-and-then-run-callback) then since you're reposting it here as your own and the original answerer never got credit from the check mark.

Comment: @iWasRobbed: I never said it was my function, I gave a link to the question, where you can see someone else made that.

Comment: @Rocket: Understood, I was just noting that the original answerer never got the check mark :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Example
A named anchor inside an HTML document:

<a name="tips">Useful Tips Section</a>
Create a link to the "Useful Tips Section" inside the same document:

<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
Or, create a link to the "Useful Tips Section" from another page:

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html_links.htm#tips">
Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
```

[source](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this library: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Answer (score 0):

**No animation basic Javascript Example (use ID instead of the name attribute)**

```
window.location = "#MasterDiv";
```

[More on window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

**Jquery Animation Example**

```
$.scrollTo("#MasterDiv");
```

[ScrollTo Jquery Plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)